# Reformatting a list of date strings to day, month, year in Python

Tags: python, list, date, datetime, format

I want to change the format of strings in a list. They are dates but have been converted into strings.

I have looked all over for this solution, but there seem to only be answers for a single element.

First I make a series

```
Date_List = df.loc['receiveddate']
print Date_List

Element1                               2015-06-26
Element2                               2015-06-25
Element3                               2015-06-26
Element4                               2015-06-25
Element5                               2015-06-25
Element6                               2015-07-01
```

Then I convert it into a list.

```
Date_List = [str(i) for i in Date_List]
```

which gives me

```
['2015-06-26', '2015-06-25', '2015-06-26', '2015-06-25', '2015-06-25', '2015-07-01']
```

Instead, I want a list of strings that go day, month, year

```
['06-26-2015', '06-25-2015...etc.]
```

I've found that the most common suggestion is to use strftime. Trying `Date_List = (datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%B %d-%Y") for i in Date_List)` Just gave me `ValueError: time data '2015-06-26' does not match format '%B %d-%Y'`

So I tried

```
Date_List = (datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d") for i in Date_List)
```

This returned `['2015-06-26 00:00:00', '2015-06-25 00:00:00', '2015-06-26 00:00:00', '2015-06-25 00:00:00', '2015-06-25 00:00:00', '2015-07-01 00:00:00']`

Does anybody know how to reformat the list? Or perhaps earlier, reformatting the Series? Thank you.

Comment: By the way, `'2015-06-26'` doesn't match the format `'%B %d-%Y'` because you're missing a hyphen: `'%B-%d-%Y'`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Adding the hyphen in didn't change the error.

Comment: Looks like you also have the `%` variables wrong. `%B` is a full month name, like `'January'`. Try `'%Y-%m-%d'` as you have elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use `datetime` here. Just map those objects to a function that turns them into strings and splits them on the `-`, then use `str.format()`:

```
Date_List = ['{}-{}-{}'.format(m,d,y) for y, m, d in map(lambda x: str(x).split('-'), Date_List)]
```

Also, from your code snippet it looks like you want the month first, not the day.

Comment: You could also say, "You don't even need to map those objects to a function that turns them into strings and splits them on the -, just use datetime"...

Comment: I could, but `datetime` is slow and all we want to do is switch the order of a hyphen-delimited string.

Comment: This worked! It's a short string so timing isn't an issue (at least in this case)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. The `datetime.datetime.strptime` converts a string into `datetime` object. You need `datetime.datetime.strftime` to convert it back to string:

```
Date_List = (datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d") for i in Date_List)
Date_List = (datetime.datetime.strftime(i, "%m-%d-%Y") for i in Date_List)
```

Comment: Ah! I forgot to add that I also tried using strftime. Both wherever I had it and using your method gives me this error which is befuddling me: TypeError: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x187808C8> is not JSON serializable

Comment: The error must be from another part of the code. datetime has nothing to do with JSON

Comment: Actually, I've figured out that your solution is creating a generator object. So to make this solution work, you need to use a list comprehension on the second line, so Date_List = [datetime.datetime.strftime(i, "%m-%d-%Y") for i in Date_List]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by a string point of view

```
New_Date_List = [d[8:10]+"-"+d[5:7]+"-"+d[:4] for d in Date_List]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your comprehension to

```
import datetime
Date_List = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for i in Date_List]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions provide a pretty straightforward solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})', r'\2-\3-\1', '2015-06-25')
'06-25-2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not pretty, it should work to generate a month-day-year list.

```
New_Date_List = [[d][5:7] + '-' + Date_List[d][-2:] + '-' + Date_List[d][:4] for d in Date_List]
```