# How can I reformat date from day-month-year to year-month-day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to remove the index and change the date format. Here is the data frame:

```
       Date    tsla    goog    aapl   msft
0    30-Dec-16  217.50  782.78  117.20  62.99
1    29-Dec-16  219.20  785.93  117.11  63.20
2    28-Dec-16  223.80  794.23  118.02  63.40
3    27-Dec-16  222.25  797.86  117.80  64.07
4    23-Dec-16  213.45  792.74  116.52  63.54
5    22-Dec-16  209.99  793.32  116.51  64.10
6    21-Dec-16  212.23  796.68  117.40  63.70
7    20-Dec-16  209.00  798.65  117.50  63.80
```

Here is how I want it to look:

```
        Date    tsla    goog    aapl   msft
   2016-12-30  217.50  782.78  117.20  62.99
   2016-12-29  219.20  785.93  117.11  63.20
   2016-12-28  223.80  794.23  118.02  63.40
   2016-12-27  222.25  797.86  117.80  64.07
   2016-12-23  213.45  792.74  116.52  63.54
   2016-12-22  209.99  793.32  116.51  64.10
   2016-12-21  212.23  796.68  117.40  63.70
   2016-12-20  209.00  798.65  117.50  63.80
```

I tried what I found here [Reformatting a list of date strings to day, month, year in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258915/reformatting-a-list-of-date-strings-to-day-month-year-in-python):

```
dfTSLA = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i), '%d-%m-%y').strftime('%y-%m-%d') for i in dfTSLA]
```

But i get the error "time data '\ufeffDate' does not match format '%d-%m-%y'", which makes sense I guess. Not sure how to go about it because the month is a string

Comment: what have you done or tried?

Comment: you don't change `day-month-year` to `year-month-day` but `day-month_name-short_year` to long_year-month_number-day`. First version you could do with string spliting and joining.

Comment: you can't remove index from dataframe - it always exist. You can save in file without index or render HTML without index or print() without index.

Comment: I've tried what I found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258915/reformatting-a-list-of-date-strings-to-day-month-year-in-python, so using strptime(). But the issue is the month is a string in my data frame. dfTSLA = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i), '%d-%m-%y').strftime('%y-%m-%d') for i in dfTSLA], throws me the error "time data '\ufeffDate' does not match format '%d-%m-%y'"

Comment: Are you trying to parse the header row as if it contained a date?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it these ways

If you want to change the type to str

```
df=pd.DataFrame(["30-Dec-16"],columns=['Date'])
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

If you want to preserve the datetime64 type

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.normalize()
```

Comment: I wouldn't convert datetime to string. If you want to get rid of time part you can do it this way: `df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.normalize()`

Comment: For whatever reason, my .dt isn't working. Its giving me some strange error. But good to know!

Comment: try this: `pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).normalize()`

Comment: You could then do this to set the data as the index: `df.set_index(['Date'], inplace=True)`